# Every time I die, the game (Skyrim) crashes

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, nintendo-switch

I’m playing Skyrim on the switch (with no mods) and all of a sudden it has this glitch that whenever I die the game crashes. I don’t know what to do, I’ve tried restarting, closing, etc. Nothing works.

Comment: Are you using a physical game card or a digital download?

Comment: Easy solution: just never die =P

Comment: Physical copy, and i ended up just making a new game, idk what to do about the other one

Answer (score 1):

I'd say to make a whole new different save on an empty save slot and then delete your older ones. I've used this to solve other glitches on other consoles like the PS4.

Comment: Didn’t work :(( still glitching for me